# ADFS3, How to set the MSISIPSelectionPersistent cookie to expired?

Tags: iis, cookies, adfs, arr, adfs3.0

Would propose Microsoft to change ADFS so that in a deployment with multiple IDPs it would be possible to still use the setting:

```
Set-ADFSWebConfig –HRDCookieEnabled $true
```

but not "forever". It's good for Web SSO, but there is no way for a user to bo back and choose again another provider (without clearing all Browser Cookies!!!!)

Sometimes a user needs to logoff and go again to the IDP selection process. My suggestion would be that Microsoft should clear MSISIPSelectionPersistent cookies when a user logs out.

there is a closed thread here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5e4bb31-9803-47aa-9939-e94e67ed7dd9/adfs3-how-to-set-the-msisipselectionpersistent-cookie-to-expired?forum=Geneva
and the workaround was to fake a /adfs scoped url to clear the protected cookie from a fake server side page.

Since I only have WAP proxy servers in my deployment, I haven't found a way yet to mask those fake pages...

any other idea? any microsoft adfs contact or uservoice?